# Save Chronometer Time?

Tags: java, android

I want to save the time of my android studio chronometer inside of a txt file that is accessable inside the app. (For Example, Click "save" button and the value of the chronometer gets saved in a txt file(keeping it accessable for later))

BTW in the code, This also has a built in counter, if that is possible to save allong with the txt file that would be AWESOME. Just am unsure how to do it

Heres my code MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Chronometer chronometer;
private long pauseOffset;
private boolean running;
private int mCounter = 0;
private Button button;
Button btn;
TextView txv;
TextView txtv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometer);


    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
    txv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx);



    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCounter++;
            txv.setText(Integer.toString(mCounter));

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PreviousRuns);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openRunHistory();
                }

            });
        }

    });
}


public void startChronometer(View v) {
    if (!running) {
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
        chronometer.start();
        running = true;
    }

}

public void pauseChronometer(View v) {
    if (running) {
        chronometer.stop();
        pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
        running = false;
    }

}

public void resetChronometer(View v) {
    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    pauseOffset = 0;
    txv.setText("0");
    mCounter = 0;
    txtv.setText("");

}

public void openRunHistory() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RunHistory.class);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you have to implement in your onClick of the save button, 'data' is the string with the time

```
    private void writeToFile(String data,Context context) {
try {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("time.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    outputStreamWriter.write(data);
    outputStreamWriter.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: When i do this it says Cannot resolve symbol 'OutputStreamWriter' Cannot resolve symbol 'Write, Cannot resolve symbol 'Close' Cannot resolve symbol 'log. Why is this,

Comment: have you tried to press alt + enter to include the libreries needed?

Comment: Thanks that worked i setup the button that will use the writeToFile by doing, >> public void buttonOnClick() {
        writeToFile(); >> But in the writeToFile it shows a red underline under the () saying >> writeToFile
(String,
Context)
in MainActivity cannot be applied
to
()

Comment: Because you have to enter the parameters in the () so you put the name of your string and then "MainActivity.this" so              writeToFile(myString, MainAcrivity.this)

Comment: Thx, i did that but all it does is crash when i click the button. I click it it reboots to a white screen and then goes to the app main screen

Comment: Post the logcat of the crash